# what was this effect(attribute?)?

Tags: html, css

I don't remember what was the name of an effect that did the following:

I have a text in a div ,  lets say the div's height is 250px  , so if the text's height is more then 250px , the other part of it that is after the 250px should hide. And i don't want there to be a scroller on the left.

Said in a few words , i need the effect(attribute?) that hides the text that is out of the bonds of a div .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a fixed height/width and add

```
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `overflow: hidden;`